# elasticsearch/kibana wirldcard searches

Tags: elasticsearch, wildcard, kibana

the elk is up and running.
Elasticsearch, Logstash, Kibana... Logs coming from Filebeat.
Kibana is showing me all the relevant Logs. I also fixed the timestamp situation. 
Everything looks awesome. I was proud!

But now, as Boss is testing it: all RegEx related Search Options are not working.

e.g.:

```
request: "/datas/somewhere/there.html" ..
request: "/datas/wheresome/there.html" ..
..
```

I want to search in kibana something like this: */datas/*/there.html*, which should replay both but it shows me nothing.
I have escaped every symbol proper etc.
Is somewhere a nice guide on how to make the classic wildcard-search ( "*", "?", ..) functional?

In other words:
How to apply the right analyzer to make wildcard-searches within the request fields working?

Comment: Thanks for all the input guys.

Can someone explain to me why i have to escape all slashes twice within the wildcard query?

Comment: "{"wildcard": {"request.keyword": "*\\/data\\/*\\/there\\.html"}}"
this is the only way kibana showing me hits. can someone explain this to me?